# How to create a new column that groups another column of values by each n numbers? Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Pandas and I'm trying to figure out if there's a module or a way to group the Price Column in the table that I've linked below to by every $n dollars.

For example, for products priced between $5-$10, I want a new column that shows that this is $5-$10, and for products between $10-$15 then in the new column it will show $10-$15.

I've done this before using conditional statements but is there a way to do this without me having to type in for this then that each time and instead someway loop it by every 5 instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share sample input\expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas.cut` to define bins:

example on dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# dummy data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': ['$%.2f' % (i/100) for i in np.random.randint(0, 5000, size=10)]})

# processing:

# convert prices to float
prices = df['price'].str[1:].astype(float)
# defines bins with $5 steps
ranges = [0]+list(range(5, int(prices.max()+5), 5))
# convert data to bins
df['price_range'] = pd.cut(prices,
                           bins=ranges,
                           labels=['$%s-$%s' % (ranges[i], ranges[i+1]) for i in range(len(ranges)-1)]
                          )
```

output:

```
    price   price_range
0   $2.18   $0-$5
1   $26.40  $25-$30
2   $2.75   $0-$5
3   $22.61  $20-$25
4   $48.93  $45-$50
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.cut()` on the price column. Try this,

```
list(df.groupby(pd.cut(df["price"], np.arange(0, max_price, 5))))
```